# Dynamic subject on send port generated email

Tags: email, biztalk, biztalk-2013, send-port

I've recently inherited a BizTalk 2013 setup and am struggling to get up to speed with it.

I have a send port which generates an email when it receives an XML file - currently it sends the file as an attachment to a specific email address. My question is how can I specify a custom subject which is based on the XML file contents. Currently, the subject is hardcoded into the properties of the port.

Having a subject will greatly help sorting the emails received, of which there are dozens everyday.

Comment: Yes it did, thanks for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your send port to a Dynamic send port, and have an Orchestration or other process that sets the SMTP.Subject property and other properties such as

e.g.

```
 Mail_MSG(SMTP.Subject) = XML_MSG.subject;
```

Search for the below in your favourite search engines for various examples

> biztalk dynamic smtp send port